# add element with attributes in minidom python

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes, minidom

I want to add a child node with attributes to a specific tag. my xml is

```
<deploy>
</deploy>
```

and the output should be

```
<deploy>
  <script name="xyz" action="stop"/>
</deploy>
```

so far my code is:

```
dom = parse("deploy.xml")
script = dom.createElement("script")
dom.childNodes[0].appendChild(script)
dom.writexml(open(weblogicDeployXML, 'w'))
script.setAttribute("name", args.script)
```

How can I figure out how to find deploy tag and append child node with attributes ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[xml.dom.Element.setAttribute](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html?highlight=setattribute#xml.dom.Element.setAttribute)

```
xmlFile = minidom.parse( FILE_PATH )

for script in SCRIPTS:

    newScript = xmlFile.createElement("script")

    newScript.setAttribute("name"  , script.name)
    newScript.setAttribute("action", script.action)

    newScriptText = xmlFile.createTextNode( script.description )

    newScript.appendChild( newScriptText  )
    xmlFile.childNodes[0].appendChild( newScript )

print xmlFile.toprettyxml()
```

Output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<scripts>
    <script action="list" name="ls" > List a directory </script>
    <script action="copy" name="cp" > Copy a file/directory </script>
    <script action="move" name="mv" > Move a file/directory </script>
    .
    .
    .
</scripts>
```

Comment: thanks william for answering this question.really help full

Comment: Thank goodness for a good answer involving `minidom` and not a redirect to `ElementTree`.