# Add tag to an XML file with Dom (minidom)

Tags: python, xml, dom

I want to add one tag to an XML file, do as follows:

```
xmlFile = parse(paths)  
tag = xmlFile.createElement("tag")
print "creado elemento materias"
tag.setAttribute("tagname"  , listaString)
xmlFile.childNodes[0].appendChild( tag)
xmlFile.toprettyxml()
```

My goal is to add a string.
The problem is that the code did not return errors but does not create the tag.

I have used as reference the question:
[add element with attributes in minidom python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911674/add-element-with-attributes-in-minidom-python)

Comment: It worked for me in Python 3.x , is your issue that xmlFile.toprettyxml() is not printing the new tag? Or is it that you are checking in the file itself, and its not coming there?

Comment: I'm checking the file itself, not the label appears. I use python 2.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlFile.toprettyxml()` returns the pretty xml as a string, it does not directly save the pretty xml to file. You would manually need to do the saving.

Example -

```
xmlFile = parse(paths)  
tag = xmlFile.createElement("tag")
print "creado elemento materias"
tag.setAttribute("tagname"  , listaString)
xmlFile.childNodes[0].appendChild( tag)
with open('<newpath to file>','w') as f:
    f.write(xmlFile.toprettyxml())
```